# Unable to generate vs code settings for c# using omnisharp

Tags: omnisharp

When I open project without .vscode folder, omnisharp used to ask me to "Generate project assets, Yes, No, Don't ask again"

And I pressed "Don't ask again" option, and found out that there is no way to restore this setting, as much as I searched in stackoverflow and other sites.

So basically with one click all of omnisharp become unusable/

What to do?